# Draw text with graphics object on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, text, jframe, draw

I am an avid programmer but today is my first Java lesson.

```
public void Paint (Graphics g)
{
    if(g instanceof Graphics2D)
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    }
    g.drawString("This is gona be awesome", 200, 200);
}
```

With the above code, I want to write a sentence on the window but it never writes. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Never mind - Paint must be paint. I apologize profusely.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In the given code, what you want is

```
 g2d.drawString("This is gona be awesome", 200, 200);
  ^
```

---

A working example for your reference :

```
package Experiments;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainClass{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame jf = new JFrame("Demo");
    Container cp = jf.getContentPane();
    MyCanvas tl = new MyCanvas();
    cp.add(tl);
    jf.setSize(300, 200);
    jf.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class MyCanvas extends JComponent {

  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      if(g instanceof Graphics2D)
      {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g2.drawString("This is gona be awesome",70,20); 
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys - i've been copying and pasting. 

Perhaps i should have look at my code some more!

P.s. should have overrided the paint method....

NOW IT WORKS FINE 

Thanks

Comment: @Sanjay please read my point `2) for Swing JComponents is there paintComponent()`, then please amend your post, `blablabla` I know that all code_depots contains paint method instead of paintComponent `balblabla`

Answer (score 2):

1) not possible directly paint to the `JFrame`, you can painting:

- put there `JPanel`
- getContentPane from `JFrame`

2) for Swing `JComponents` is there `paintComponent()` instead of `paint()`, otherwise your painting couldn't be drawed corretly

3) another options are:

- paint to the `JFrame's RootPane`
- paint to the `JFrame's GlassPane`

4) more in [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) tutorial

Answer (score 1):

To draw text on the screen with JFrame, you can use the `Graphics.drawText(String text, int x, int y)` method.

The first parameter is the string that you want to display and the last two parameters are the coordinates where this text will start.

Here is some example code:

```
package example.com;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JFrameGraphics extends JPanel {

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawString("Hello Text!", 10, 10);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame frame= new JFrame("Hello");  
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JFrameGraphics());
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);      
    }
}
```

Check out to learn more about how to display text and graphics in Java: https://javatutorial.net/display-text-and-graphics-java-jframe