# JFrame: How to display text without JTextArea/JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to display text in between these boxes, so that each row looks something like:

```
{Image of a d20} {Input1} d20 + {Input2} {Roll button}.
```

This is an odd question, but [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7m8Fa.png) should make things clearer.

[image]

Comment: I'd guess that you should use a JLabel, but what is a "d20", and what does its image look like?

Comment: There are a method in Swing called JLabel that accepts HTML formatting. That could possibly be used.

Comment: Yes I agree, if you only want to display an image, JLabel is the simplest way to do this by using its `setIcon` method.

Comment: I wonder if you really want to display a JTable, but until I get a better feel for what it is you are exactly trying to do, I'll have to put this idea on the shelf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Graphics object for your JPanel actually can draw text on it's own by invoking the drawString command. I'll post an example, but I think it will be most helpful to read the full example that explains it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802320/draw-text-with-graphics-object-on-jframe) or [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076869/learn-java/drawing-text-is-easy-with-three-java-classes.html) (I personally like the second one, but the first is a Stack Overflow question):

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
   super.paintComponent(g);
   g.drawString("abc", 25, 25);
}
```

I almost flagged this as a duplicate, but it is technically a distinct question. I would recommend just a little more searching before posting though.

EDIT:

To more thoroughly explain how this might be helpful, you could have a custom JPanel element that holds your

```
{Image of a d20} {Input1} d20 + {Input2} {Roll button}.
```

which draws the text, image, inputs, and buttons local to a JPanel holding all of them. This JPanel will have a paintComponent() method where you can use the above code. Then  just include that in your JFrame. It makes your code a little more modular and easy to organize as you're grouping relevant components. I hope you find this helpful.

Happy coding! Leave a comment if you have any questions.

Comment: I edited the post to show better practices. This will slightly conflict with some of the reference links, but in an important way.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks for the edits. Today is a typo-ridden day. Do you agree with the thought of making a custom component to house his related bits?

Comment: Perhaps best would be to use a GridBagLayout to format the fields/labels in a proper grid.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use JLabel and set it's text as needed, or define the JTextField to act like JLabel

Answer (score 0):

Use jLabel you can set the text like this:

```
yourlabel.setText("your text");
```

Or you can get the text from a jLabel like this:

```
String str = yourlabel.getText();
```

The String "str" would be "your text".